# How to see that the Laplacian of a positive vector field results in a negative vector field (or negative component).

Tags: vector-fields, laplacian

In a x,y,z cartesian coordinate system with the z-axis positive downwards, equations (1) and (2) are "equivalent", in that they both describe how the vector field $\mathbf{v}$ is governed by the vector $(\nabla p - \rho \mathbf{g})$:
$$\tag{1} \mu \nabla ^2 \mathbf{v} = \nabla p - \rho \mathbf{g}; \ \ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}=0$$
$$\tag{2} \mathbf{v}=-\frac{f(\mathbf{x})}{\mu}(\nabla p - \rho \mathbf{g}); \ \ \nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}=0$$

However, after distributing the leading negative sign in Eqn(2), we have $(-\nabla p + \rho \mathbf{g})$. Thus, the $\nabla p$ and $\rho \mathbf{g}$ terms have opposite signs in Eqns(1) and (2). This leads me to think that Eqns(1) and (2) are not "equivalent". I think my confusion is due to Eqn(1) is written for $\nabla ^2 \mathbf{v}$ rather than for $\mathbf{v}$ as is for Eqn(2). **Does the quantity $\nabla ^2 \mathbf{v}$ in Eqn(1) lead to a negative quantity, where the negative sign can be distributed to the vector $(\nabla p - \rho \mathbf{g})$, and if 'yes' can you show me how?**

Comment: Can you clarify what is $f(x)$? and how is it related to $v$ and $p$ etc. 

BTW, is this some Poisson equation for vector fields?

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 $f(\mathbf{x})$ is some function of position; a scalar.

Comment: Without knowing more about what is $f(x)$ I cannot tell how the two equations relates... (you can absorb any negative sign into the $f(x)$ right?

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 Eqn(1) is Stoke's eqn for incompressible Newtonian fluid flow. In trying to derive an equation for incompressible Newtonian fluid flow through a porous medium we have Eqn(2). The structure of the 3-dimensional pore space for a porous medium such as a rock (say) is "complex" and unknown. Therefore, the unknown boundary conditions of the pore space of a porous medium makes solving Eqn(1) impractical. The unknown boundary conditions of the pore space at some position $\mathbf{x}$ will govern the flow in some way at that point in space, which is being represented by the function $f$.

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 I also note that in Eqns(1) and (2) $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{v}=0$.

Comment: This reminds me of this vector laplacian identity, which could give rise to a negative sign. Is there any other thing we know about the curl of the vector field v?
  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#Vector_Laplacian

Comment: @BinxuWang王彬旭 the no-slip condition for viscous fluids assumes that at a solid boundary, the fluid will have zero velocity $\mathbf{v}$ relative to the solid boundary. We assume the solid boundary to be stationary. Thus, when a positive flow occurs, the velocity profile will be "parabolic" in shape. The flow velocity profile cannot be a flat surface. I recall something along the lines that the Laplacian of a function at a local maximum will result in a value with a negative sign. So perhaps the answer lies somewhere within this reasoning? Your thoughts?